# round time to previous 15 min javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

i want to get the prvious round 15 minutes from a given time or date in js for example i have 11:20 i want to get 11:15 , 12:57 i want to get 12:45 , i tried this :

```
      var round = 1000 * 60 * 15;
      var date = new Date()
      console.log(date)
      var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / round) * round)
```

but this give me the nearest 15 minutes not the previous , for 15:57 for example it give me 16:00 when i want to get 15:45
any solution ?

Comment: use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`

Comment: There is also `date.setMinutes((date.getMinutes() / 15 | 0) * 15, 0, 0)` where `| 0` behaves like *Math.floor*. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) instead of [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) (as mentioned by @ciekals in comments) if you want to get the previous time.

`Math.round` will give the next 15 mins time if the time is closer to it e.g. 7:29 will give 7:30 if you use `Math.round`. But if you want 7:29 to return 7:15, then you should use `Math.floor`.

```js
 var round = 1000 * 60 * 15;
var date = new Date()
console.log(date)
var rounded = new Date(Math.floor(date.getTime() / round) * round)
console.log(rounded)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use modulus to round down

```
var rounded = new Date(date.getTime()-(date.getTime()%round)))
```

this way you remove the amount by which `date` differs from being a multiple of `round`

Comment: % is a [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder), it does not behave like modulo.